# I want to implement a custom list method in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
extension MyMethod on List<int>{
void forEachCustom(void Function(int) other){
for(var e in this){
other(e); 
    }   
  }
}
void main(){
  List<int> a=[1,2,3,4];
  a.forEachCustom(print);
}
```

> This just prints the elements. I want to implement my custom list method that performs operation on the original receiver on which I call the method. Example ,sort() method, that already exists,as it dosent return anything but modifies the list to which we call it

Comment: `saving the changes in variable a` can describe more about this what are you trying to get as result.

Comment: So you want to map in place?

Comment: I have edited my question, please see if it is understandable now

Comment: Why you want to create something when it is already exists? As I understand, you want to pass `sort` method?

Comment: Straightaway saying, I want to implement my custom list method that performs operation on the original receiver on which I call the method. Sort was an example as it dosent return anything but modify the list to which we call it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your question, but you can easily sort a list in dart with predefined method

```dart
extension MyMethod on List<int>{
   void forEachCustom(void Function(int) other){
      sort(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Straightaway saying, I want to implement my custom list method that performs operation on the original receiver on which I call the method. Sort was an example as it dosent return anything but modify the list to which we call it.